# ¿Cómo crear una función para que al presionar enter cambie de TextField a otro TextField en reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

como puedo hacer esto en React.js por medio de funcion o clase, usando Textfield y pasar de un campo a otro, usando Material UI con React.js

```js
function nextFocus(inputF, inputS) {
  document.getElementById(inputF).addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      document.getElementById(inputS).focus();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" onkeypress="nextFocus('input1', 'input2')"><br>
<input type="text" id="input2" onkeypress="nextFocus('input2', 'input3')"><br>
<input type="text" id="input3" onkeypress="nextFocus('input3', 'input4')"><br>
<input type="text" id="input4"><br>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es recomendable incluir los eventos dentro de la misma etiqueta y, además, en la función estás creando un "escuchador" para poder obtener la tecla pulsada. Intenta:

- Obtener todos los campos en una sola colección, que te permita manipularlos fácilmente
- Con `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="input"]');` obtienes todo lo que tenga ID que comience con *input*
- Recorres la colección para asignar el evento
- Dentro de la función verificas si se pulsó la tecla ENTER
- Obtienes número del elemento en que se disparó el evento
- Verificas que no es el último y pasa el foco al siguiente elemento

```js
// Colección de inputs con índices de (0 a 3)
// 0 es la posición de #input1, 3 es la posición de #input4
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="input"]');
// Asignar evento para ejecutar función
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('keypress', nextFocus));

// Recibe evento como parámetro
function nextFocus(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        // e.target es el elemento que lanzó el evento
        // Obtener número desde ID, eliminando la palabra input (1 a 4)
        let actual = parseInt(e.target.id.replace('input', ''));
        // Solo si no es el último
        if(actual < inputs.length) {
            // Evitar comportamiento normal del evento
            e.preventDefault();
            // Activar siguiente campo
            inputs[actual].focus();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1"><br>
<input type="text" id="input2"><br>
<input type="text" id="input3"><br>
<input type="text" id="input4"><br>
```